# Unable to enable extension PostGIS for greenplum 5.1

Tags: greenplum

I am trying to enable PostGis extension for green plum but unable to do that. While running ./configure I get following error which says PostgreSql version is not supported. Which Greenplum version comes with Postgresql 9.0 or above? OR is there any way to upgrade Postgresql version for greenplum? OR is there any wayto enable PostGis for Postgresql version 8.3.

```
configure: WARNING: dblatex is not installed so PDF documentation cannot be built
configure: WARNING: could not locate Docbook stylesheets required to build the documentation
checking CUnit/CUnit.h usability... no
checking CUnit/CUnit.h presence... no
checking for CUnit/CUnit.h... no
configure: WARNING: could not locate CUnit required for unit tests
checking iconv.h usability... yes
checking iconv.h presence... yes
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for libiconv_open in -liconv... no
checking for iconv_open in -lc... yes
checking for iconvctl... no
checking for libiconvctl... no
Using user-specified pg_config file: /usr/local/greenplum-db-5.1.0/bin/pg_config
checking PostgreSQL version... PostgreSQL 8.3.23
configure: error: PostGIS requires PostgreSQL >= 9.0
```

Comment: https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/43180/ref_guide/extensions/postGIS.html , no?

Comment: Greenplum does not "come with Postgres". It's a _fork_ (=separated development) of a very old Postgres version - it's a different DBMS

Comment: thanks for the answer. I was struggling to get postgis working for greenplum. Finally gave up

Comment: Download PostGIS package from pivotal network site.